# Is packing a bag of presents easier for Rupert than Santa?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, optimization, packing

<sup>Or: Do we need Rupert in order to get presents at all?</sup>

[Routing issues](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6531/can-santa-be-both-fair-and-efficient) aside, Santa faces the following problem (many, many times over):

> Given a bag with capacity¹ $C$ and a set of presents $\{p_1, \dots, p_n\}$, each with size $s_i$, he wants to make children $\{c_1, \dots, c_k\}$ happy. He knows from all the wish lists that child $c_j$ values present $p_i$ exactly $v_{i,j} \in \mathbb{Q}_{\geq 0}$ much.
>
> Which (pairwise disjoint) sets of presents $I_j \subseteq [1..n]$ to pick for each child so that everything fits, i.e.
>
> $\qquad\displaystyle \sum_{j \in [1..k]} \sum_{i \in I_j} s_i \leq C$,
>
> and as much happiness as possible ensues², i.e.
>
> $\qquad\displaystyle \max! \sum_{j \in [1..k]} \sum_{i \in I_j} v_{i,j}$ ?

This is clearly not easier than Bin Packing or Knapsack, so poor Santa may have to spend a long time packing bags³.

[image: PD by 1212eins@pixabay.com]

Now, as we know, his assistant Rupert does not give as unconditionally. He has knowledge about $V_j$, the maximum value child $c_j$ may receive based on behaviour during the year; that is, he adds an additional constraint

> $\qquad\displaystyle \forall j \in [1..k].\ \sum_{i \in I_j} v_{i,j} \leq V_j$.

Does that make the problem of packing bags easier? If not always, then under which conditions?

---

1. If the *c*himney diameter is the limiting factor, a similar framework can be established.
2. Let's not concern ourselves with fairness and other ridiculuous ideas.
3. Hence, only one Christmas per year. Q.E.D.

Comment: Everybody who wants to give to fellow users, add a bounty once that's possible! Correct and understandable answers who *also* conjure the spirit of the holidays the most will be eligible!

Comment: My older Christmas questions [on Santa-routing](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6531/can-santa-be-both-fair-and-efficient) and [on cookie tiling](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/35212/how-many-cookies-in-the-cookie-box-tiling-stars) are both at least partially open, too!

Comment: Bah! ...  Humbug!

Comment: A couple of trivial comments: the problem cannot always be easier (just pick $V_j \ge \sum_{i\in I_j} v_{i,j}$) but there is at least one case in which it is (set all $V_j=0$ except $V_1$, which is set to $\min_i v_{i,1}$).

Answer (score 1):

After quickly looking at this question, I believe Rupert's extra knowledge of each child's {behavior, max value present} will not *always* make Santa's job easier. Santa will still need to perform a 0/1 knapsack to fill the bags and a Hungarian algorithm as well to maximize the happiness each capitalist child receives on Christmas morning. A simple case where it would make Santa's job quite simple is if every child Santa was considering didn't publish a paper and instead played video games all year received a zero from Rupert (each child would get coal).